# How to create a "timer" in python?

Tags: python, timer

Is it possible to make the script drop everything it's been doing if a timer hits a certain time?

Let's say I want it to run for 24 hours and after that it should print a few things and then exit.

Comment: time.sleep(24*60*60)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty rude method but it will work. REMEMBER: put your code after the else statement or it won't work. Also, modify the comment above exit() as the comment said.
PS.: this are built-in modules. No need to install anything.

```
    import datetime
    from sys import exit

    starting_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    while True:
        actual_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
        if actual_datetime > starting_time + datetime.timedelta(days=1):
            # do what you need to do before it shut down
            exit()
        else:
            # RUN YOUR PROGRAM HERE
```

Comment: Also, you can't use time.sleep() because it will only delay your current thread for a day and it won't tun your code in a "sort of parallel way"